# How to install php in docker httpd container

Tags: php, docker, apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to install php in a docker container.

I'm using [docker httpd image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). I know that their are images that include apache and php together, but i need to install php seperately.

I haven't found any documentation on how to do this. Note that i'm not using dockerfile.

If anyone could guide me through the steps or provide me some documentation on how to achieve this I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

PS. I have already got my apache server up and running, i have configured everything, only missing the php part so if this could be done without restarting it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

To install PHP just create `Dockerfile` with this content:

```
FROM php:<version>
```

Example:

```
FROM php:7.4
```

And in docker-compose.yml write:

```
php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    volumes:
     - ".:/app"
```

Then build project with composer and thats it.

Comment: Can i do this without a dockerfile? I already have my apache running. I created the container with docker run -d --name apache-server -p 80:80 httpd command

Comment: Sorry that i'm not sure if you can do thus. But try your command edited to php setup